# Albums for classical songs played by electric guitar?

Tags: classical-music, metal, album

I am after an album of classical songs such as Vivaldi's four seasons played by electric guitars. I did a search about some neoclassical metal guitarists; but so far I have not yet found something I want. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uli Jon Roth is your man.

In his album [Metamorphosis of Vivaldi's Four Seasons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metamorphosis_of_Vivaldi%27s_Four_Seasons)
he plays his version of Vivaldi's Four Seasons.
Also there is his album [Prologue to the symphonic legends](https://www.discogs.com/Sky-Of-Avalon-Prologue-To-The-Symphonic-Legends/release/2117815)
in which he also plays some classical songs. Also check his live albums where he plays a lot of classical compositions arranged for electric guitar.

Answer (score 2):

For Vivaldi's "Four seasons", try albums by At Vance:

- [No Escape](http://themetalclub.com/albums/14585/), featuring "Summer"
- [Only Human](http://themetalclub.com/albums/14586/), - featuring "Spring"
- [Ride The Sky](http://themetalclub.com/albums/14587/), featuring "Summer" (another version)

There are other classical covers performed by this band.
If you are generally into neoclassical rock/metal, try Symphony X. Their own music has a lot of inspirations and direct musical quotes from classical works.

Of course, Yngwie Malmsteen mentioned in the previous answer is worth starting with as a founder of neoclassical hard rock.

Also worth listening are both Wolf Hoffmann’s solo albums: **Classical** and **Headbanger Symphony.**

https://youtu.be/F-WazDQZu0I - The Night On The Bald Mountain official video.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to this album: `Concerto Suite for Electric Guitar and Orchestra` by `Yngwie Malmsteen`.

The track list is the follow:

1. "Icarus Dream Fanfare"  5:15
2. "Cavallino Rampante"    3:58
3. "Fugue" 3:38
4. "Prelude to April"  2:43
5. "Toccata"   3:58
6. "Andante"   4:19
7. "Sarabande" 3:22
8. "Allegro"   1:30
9. "Adagio"    3:09
10. "Vivace"    4:50
11. "Presto Vivace" 3:39
12. "Finale"    1:50

It contains classical pieces by Vivaldi, Paganini, Bach, Beetoven.

[English Wikipedia page about this album](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concerto_Suite_for_Electric_Guitar_and_Orchestra)

Comment: I think that these are Yngiwie's compositions and the album itself does not contain pieces by Vivaldi, Paganini, Bach and Beethoven. Quoting the Wikipedia article that you linked: 'All of the music was composed by Malmsteen'

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of adding to what seems to be one of those awkward list questions:

The band [Sky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sky_(English/Australian_band)) recorded modern arrangements of many classical pieces, usually featuring acoustic and/or electric guitars:

- Perhaps most notably, an arrangement of Bach's [*Toccata and Fugue in D minor*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toccata_and_Fugue_in_D_minor,_BWV_565)
- Wagner's *Ride Of The Valkyries*
- and pieces by Handel, Satie, Mozart, Ravel, and others.

And one of their members was behind:

- [*Beyond The Planets*](https://www.discogs.com/master/58073-Jeff-Wayne-Rick-Wakeman-Kevin-Peek-Beyond-The-Planets), a 1984 arrangement of Holst's Planets suite by Kevin Peek and Rick Wakeman, mostly on keyboards but with some electric guitar (also featuring Greg Schulz, Trevor Spencer, a piece by Jeff Wayne, and narration by Patrick Allen).

Answer (score 0):

Some very skilled guitar players favouring classical works, including Vivaldi (here are their Youtube channels):

[Dr.Viossy](https://www.youtube.com/@DRVIOSSY)
[Tina S](https://www.youtube.com/@TinaS/featured) (guitary prodigy who alas went MIA from the public eye)